# What is meant by "classes themselves are objects"?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I was just reading the Python documentation about classes; it says, in Python "classes themselves are objects". How is that different from classes in C#, Java, Ruby, or Smalltalk?
What advantages and disadvantages does this type of classes have compared with those other languages?

Answer (score 9):

In Python, classes are objects in the sense that you can assign them to variables, pass them to functions, etc. just like any other objects. For example

```
>>> t = type(10)
>>> t
<type 'int'>
>>> len(t.__dict__)
55
>>> t() # construct an int
0
>>> t(10)
10
```

Java has `Class` objects which provide some information about a class, but you can't use them in place of explicit class names. They aren't really classes, just class information structures.

```java
Class C = x.getClass();
new C(); // won't work
```

Comment: In java you create new instances of a class this way: 
Object o = C.newInstance();

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a class is simply declaring a variable:

```
class foo(object):
    def bar(self): pass
print foo # <class '__main__.foo'>
```

They can be assigned and stored like any variable:

```
class foo(object):
    pass
class bar(object):
    pass
baz = bar # simple variable assignment
items = [foo, bar]
my_foo = items[0]() # creates a foo
for x in (foo, bar): # create one of each type
    print x()
```

and passed around as a variable:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "created foo"
def func(f):
    f()

func(foo)
```

They can be created by functions, including the base class list:

```
def func(base_class, var):
    class cls(base_class):
        def g(self):
            print var
    return cls

class my_base(object):
    def f(self): print "hello"

new_class = func(my_base, 10)
obj = new_class()
obj.f() # hello
obj.g() # 10
```

By contrast, while classes in Java have objects representing them, eg. String.class, the class name itself--String--isn't an object and can't be manipulated as one.  That's inherent to statically-typed languages.

Answer (score 2):

In C# and Java the classes are not objects. They are types, in the sense in which those languages are statically typed. True you can get an object representing a specific class - but that's not the same as the class itself.

In python what looks like a class is actually an object too.

It's exlpained [here](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) much better than I can ever do :)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that they mean you can easily manipulate the class as an object.  The same facility is available in Java, where you can use the methods of [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to get at information about the class of an object.  In languages like Python, Ruby, and Smalltalk, the more dynamic nature of the language lets you "open" the class and change it, which is sometimes called "monkey patching".

Personally I don't think the differences are all that much of a big deal, but I'm sure we can get a good religious war started about it.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are objects in that they are manipulable in Python code just like any object. Others have shown how you can pass them around to functions, allowing them to be operated upon like any object. Here is how you might do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

f = Foo()

f.a = "a"    # assigns attribute on instance f
Foo.b = "b"  # assigns attribute on class Foo, and thus on all instances including f

print f.a, f.b
```

Second, like all objects, classes are instantiated at runtime.  That is, a class definition is code that is *executed* rather than a structure that is *compiled* before anything runs. This means a class can "bake in" things that are only known when the program is run, such as environment variables or user input. These are evaluated once when the class is declared and then become a part of the class.  This is different from compiled languages like C# which require this sort of behavior to be implemented differently.

Finally, classes, like any object, are built from classes. Just as an object is built from a class, so is a class built from a special kind of class called a *metaclass.* You can write your own metaclasses to change how classes are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage of classes being objects is that objects can change their class at runtime:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print "Yo There! I'm a MyCLass-Object!"
...
>>> class YourClass(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print "Guess what?! I'm a YourClass-Object!"
...
>>> o = MyClass()
>>> o.foo()
Yo There! I'm a MyCLass-Object!
>>> o.__class__ = YourClass
>>> o.foo()
Guess what?! I'm a YourClass-Object!
```

Objects have a special attribute `__class__` that points to the class of which they are an instance. This is possible only because classes are objects themself, and therefore can be bound to an attribute like `__class__`.

Answer (score 1):

As this question has a Smalltalk tag, this answer is from a Smalltalk perspective. In Object-Oriented programming, things get done through message-passing. You send a message to an object, if the object understands that message, it executes the corresponding method and returns a value. But how is the object created in the first place? If special syntax is introduced for creating objects that will break the simple syntax based on message passing. This is what happens in languages like Java:

```
p = new Point(10, 20); // Creates a new Point object with the help of a special keyword - new.
p.draw(); // Sends the message `draw` to the Point object.
```

As it is evident from the above code, the language has two ways to get things done - one imperative and the other Object Oriented. In contrast, Smalltalk has a consistent syntax based only on messaging:

```
p := Point new: 10 y: 20.
p draw.
```

Here `new` is a message send to a singleton object called `Point` which is an instance of a `Metaclass`. In addition to giving the language a consistent model of computation, metaclasses allow dynamic modification of classes. For instance, the following statement will add a new instance variable to the `Point` class without requiring a recompilation or VM restart:

```
Point addInstVarName: 'z'.
```

The best reading on this subject is [The Art of the Metaobject Protocol](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262610744).